# how do I fix the error "Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully" while pip install html?

Tags: html, plugins

while doing pip install html, it shows the error

Collecting html
Using cached html-1.16.tar.gz (7.6 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [17 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\raigo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 353, in 
main()
File "c:\users\raigo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 335, in main
json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
File "c:\users\raigo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return hook(config_settings)
File "C:\Users\raigo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ewv_jwxr\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
File "C:\Users\raigo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ewv_jwxr\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
self.run_setup()
File "C:\Users\raigo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ewv_jwxr\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
File "C:\Users\raigo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ewv_jwxr\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
exec(code, locals())
File "", line 12, in 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

it should install html, but here I think some package missing or some internal code missing